# collect attribute from multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have few SQL tables, say `T1, T2, T3`, each having 2 attributes `date, some_id`. I want collect all Ids from each table for given date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE, SOME_ID from T1
WHERE DATE = &&Date
ORDER BY SOME_ID desc;
```

Is there a way to obtain table of the form:

```
DATE SOME_ID1 SOME_ID2 SOME_ID3
31/12/2019 id1 id2 id3
...
```

Not using query below?

```
SELECT T1.DATE,
       T1.SOME_ID AS SOME_ID1,
       T2.SOME_ID AS SOME_ID2,
       T3.SOME_ID AS SOME_ID3,
FROM T1
JOIN T2
   ON T1.DATE = T2.DATE
      AND T2.DATE = &&Date
JOIN T3
   ON T1.DATE = T3.DATE
      AND T3.DATE = &&Date
ORDER BY SOME_ID1, SOME_ID2, SOME_ID3
```

I'm asking because i have much more than 3 tables.

Sample data:
T1:

```
date some_id
31/12/2019 25
31/12/2019 11
31/05/2019 12
31/08/2019 124
```

T2:

```
date some_id
31/01/2019 205
31/08/2019 101
31/12/2019 120
31/08/2019 14
```

T3:

```
date some_id
31/03/2019 245
31/08/2019 141
28/02/2019 129
30/06/2019 114
31/12/2019 651
```

Expected output for `&&Date = 31/12/2019`:

```
DATE SOME_ID1 SOME_ID2 SOME_ID3
31/12/2019 25 120 651
31/12/2019 11 120 651
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Please only tag one DBMS.

Comment: Sample data and expect results would be helpful. I'm not sure what kind of output you need or the structure of the tables. Is there only one `some_id` per date in each table?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry added samples

Comment: Why are they separate tables any away?

Comment: @Strawberry because question is: is it possible to combine *multiple* tables into one without repeating code multiple times?

Comment: Sure, but sometimes it's smarter to take a more holistic approach; this kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: @Strawberry, agree that it is poor schema, I'm just data user, trying to get best from what I got

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `union`?

```
SELECT DATE, SOME_ID 
FROM T1
WHERE DATE = &&Date
UNION
SELECT DATE, SOME_ID 
FROM T2
WHERE DATE = &&Date
UNION
SELECT DATE, SOME_ID 
FROM T3
WHERE DATE = &&Date
```

Comment: This probably works but if i have more tables i would need to do a lot of copy pasting. I was after solution which is sort of loop. Not sure if what I'm after is feasible at all, just want to know if repeating is the only possibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use full outer joins, as in:

```
select
  coalesce(a.my_date, b.my_date, c.my_date) as my_date,
  a.some_id as some_id1,
  b.some_id as some_id2,
  c.some_id as some_id3
from (
  select distinct my_date, some_id from t1 where date = &&date
) a
full outer join (
  select distinct my_date, some_id from t2 where date = &&date
) b
full outer join (
  select distinct my_date, some_id from t3 where date = &&date
) c
```

You can easily expand this query using the strategy shown above to many tables.